# Windows 8.1 Pro error on customize in personal folder

Tags: windows-8.1

I have almost a fresh install of Windows 8.1 Pro, all I have done after that is some tweaks using Windows 8 Manager.
So when I go to my personal folder on the desktop, and then I right click and choose Customize... it gives me an error
"Explorer.EXE unspecified error", and thats it...
I have searched for similar problems but they are all for Windows 7
So can anyone help me please?

EDIT: This Customize Folder option works ok in other folders, but inside my personal folder on the desktop it gives the error...

Comment: We'll need more info/clarification.  Your "personal folder" on the desktop? What's that mean exactly? Does it work as expected in other folders? What's the exact error it gives you? What is "Windows 8 Manager", and what 'tweaks' did you perform exactly?  For the suggestions/solution you found for Windows 7, which did you try already, and what were the results?

Comment: That is esxactly the error I receive, thats it.
and yes, I am talking about my personal folder, named after my account
EDITED

Comment: You won't just automatically get a "personal folder" on your desktop; someone/something had to put it there.  So, where did yours come from?  Is it just a standard run-of-the-mill folder you created yourself? If you just delete the folder, and create it again, does it work?  Have you performed disk checks to ensure you have no disk/file-system corruption?  Anything related to the error in the Event Logs? Any answers to my other enquires?

Comment: dude... I am talking about the personal folder, named after your account, which contains Pictures, Downloads, Music, Links, Favorites.......

Comment: Homie... from me experience, that doesn't just end up on your Windows desktop, that's what is confusing me.   Anyhow, I'm obviously having trouble following you, and you seem to be adverse to answering all my requests for clarification for some reason, so I will bow out.  Good luck!